# Difference between contains and contains<> in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I may be stupid, but what is the difference between `contains` and `contains<>` in VS whisper help? Sometimes I get both, sometimes only the one with <>.

They things is that I am trying to use contains in where as in some solutions found here on SO, but it throws error that I best overload method has some invalid arguments (them method is `System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Contains<TSource>(...)`).

My code is like this:

```
defaultDL = db.SomeEntity
                    .Where(dl => dl.Something == this.Something
                        && (dl.AllLocation == true || this.SomeOtherEntity.Select(loc => loc.Location).Contains(dl.Location)))
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: `Contains<>` doesn't exist. Maybe you meant `Contains<T>`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, but it's written `code`(Contains<>) in the VS whisper so I copy it here like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you navigate to definition of `System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains` method, you will see that it is declared as generic extension method.

```
public static bool Contains<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TSource value);
```

The reason why sometimes it is called with `<type>` arguments, and sometimes not - is because most of the time compiler will analize it's arguments and determine type automatically. So under the hood, it will be rewritten to explicit generic call.

Like

```
someCollection.Contains(someValue);
```

actually is being compiled to

```
Enumerable.Contains<CollectionInnerType>(someCollection, someValue);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it get through my mind when I realized the connection with Enumerable.

Answer (score 1):

Linq has extension method `Contains<>`. When you are using it - you can enter type parameters, or not. If you are not enter - c# compiler will try to specify arguments implicitly.

Some other enumerable classes (e.g. `List<>`) implement own `Contain` method.

So, when IntelliSense suggest `Contains<>` method - it is an implementation from Linq; when `Contains` - it is own implementation of concrete class.

About difference in implementation. Own implementation of class seems to be faster, than Linq implementation, because Linq implementation is more abstract from endpoint class.

Comment: `Contains<>` doesn't exist. Maybe you meant `Contains<T>`?

Comment: of course I mean `Contains<T>`. But in author's terminology it looks like `Contains<>`

Comment: actually, i think that there is no difference. `method_name<>` - is a method called `method_name` with one generic parameter, `method_name<,>` - with two, etc

Comment: Try to write `Contains<>` and you'll get a build error. The generic version needs at least one parameter (and in this case only one), like `Contains<TSource>`

Comment: In this case - try to write `Contains<T>` and you will get build error too, cause there is no class called `T`. I think, anyone, who used generics will understand what I meant in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities. But here are the most common.

I'm guessing `SomeOtherEntity` is a reference to an `ICollection<T>`. That is a standard method on `ICollection` that scans in memory for reference equality (depending on implementation). [You can read about that here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5cf1d56(v=vs.110).aspx).

There also is the `Contains<T>` which comes from LINQ. It is an extension method. It works on `IEnumerable<T>` which `ICollection<T>` is derived from. [You can read about this one here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb352880(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It has the following basic difference.

1. Contains is an Extension method while Contains is not.
2. Contains retrun `IEnumerable<T>` while Contais return bool value and determines whether your item is present or not. In Contain you can pass deligates that based on condition will return `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: `Contains<>` doesn't exist. Maybe you meant `Contains<T>`?

Comment: Yes I mean Contains<T>, Updating my answer.